# call values from previous mysql query

Tags: mysql

Suppose you have the following MySQL statement,

```
 SELECT COUNT(downloads) as dl<br>
    FROM files<br>
    GROUP BY file_id
```

and you've generated the results of your first query.  How then do you call `dl` in another select query right after it?  Because I would like to perform another operation on `dl`.  I do not want to do it in the same query unless I have to.

Comment: Does your query results yield more than one row?

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can say following and use `@dl` in later queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(downloads) as dl
into @dl
FROM files
GROUP BY file_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is rather vague.

You could store it in a variable in whatever is sending the queries to mysqld. You could store it in a session variable in mysqld. You could write it into a table in mysql. You could just join your curernt query to the query where you want to use the value. You could wrap both (all?) queries in a procedure. If you've got result caching enabled then you could just run the query again to fetch the value from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary table if you're storing multiple rows:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE downloads_per_file (id int, dl int);

INSERT INTO downloads_per_file
SELECT file_id, COUNT(downloads) as dl
FROM files
GROUP BY file_id
```

Within the same session you can use the temporary table like any other; when the connection is closed, the table is destroyed.